# How to parametrize datasource in the user control based on ASPxGridView?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, user-controls, devexpress, datasource

**Summary:** The same user control displays notes at different levels of ASPxGridView nesting. How to parametrize the user control?

**Details:** I want to display a ASPxGridView for **Projects**. Each DetailRow for the project displays the nested ASPxGridView with **Milestones** and another ASPxGridView **Notes** at the same level (inside the same DetailRow).

The Milestones grid view row can also be expanded to show details. The detail of the milestone contains also **Notes** -- at a different level of nesting. See the picture:[image: nesting of gridviews]

The green-framed ASPxGridView with its SqlDataSource (named `dsNotes`) is the user control named `NotesControl`.

The upper-level `NotesControl` displays the UNION of notes of both the project and of all the project milestones. If the user wants, he/she can expand the milestone to see only the notes related to the milestone.

The SqlDataSource of the `NotesControl` uses the stored procedure `sp_notes` with arguments `@idproj` and `@idmilestone`. The default value `-1` says that the argument should not apply. This way the `sp_notes` can return or all notes for all projects, all notes for a given project (that is the project and its milestones), or only the given milestone notes.

**Need to know:** How should I correctly pass the `idproj` and `idmilestone` to the `NotesControl` user component?

**What I tried:** Earlier, my `NotesControl` used `..._BeforePerformDataSelect` event handler to fill `Session["idproj"]` and `Session["idmilestone"]`. The SqlDataSource arguments of the `dsNotes` were bound to the Session. However, the `Session` lookup table is global, and it is not capable to store the argument values for separate instances of the `NotesControl`.

What is the recommended way to do that? Possibly some alternatives?

**Update:** Adopting the advice to introduce the `NotesControl`-class properties named `ProjectID` and `MilestoneID`, and having the following definition of the `dsNotes` datasource in the `NotesControl.ascx`... Can I modify the HTML fragment so, that it pass the property values somehow?

```html
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsNotes" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:app_db_ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="sp_notes" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="" Name="idproj" SessionField="idproj" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="" Name="idmilestone" SessionField="idmilestone" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: You can create 2 properties in your user control and set them from your page.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I am fluent with OO programming (C++), but new to APS.NET programming. So, I can define a property (in the class definition) of the user control, and then set it from the outer code. I guess that the ASP.NET framework creates instances of the user control somewere behind the scene. If the data source is part of the user control, how I pass the property value as its stored-procedure argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create two public properties in the user control.
Then set them when you want to access the user control and then use that properties to bind the `datasource`.

Example-

```
 namespace projects.WebApplication.mySystem.Controls
 {
  public partial class myusercontrol: System.Web.UI.UserControl
  {
    public event EventHandler Close;
    public event EventHandler Show;

    public int MilestoneID{get;set;}
    public int ProjectID{get;set;}

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
          yourgridview.Datasource= MyDatabaseHelper.GetGridData(MilestoneID,ProjectID);
          yourgridview.DataBind();
        }
    }
  }
 }
```

---

**UPDATE**

There are two ways to achieve what you want

1) Going by your current HTML code and using session variables just update the session variables in properties set

```
  private int _mileStoneID = int.MinValue;
  public int MilestoneID{get{return _mileStoneID;}set{
    Session["idmilestone"] = value;
    _mileStoneID = value;
  }}
```

and do the same for the other property

2) You can change your ASP tag script code as below,

```
 <SelectParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="MilestoneID" Type="Int32" DefaultValue=0/>
    <asp:Parameter Name="ProjectID" Type="Int32" DefaultValue=0/>
</SelectParameters>
```

and then in `pageload`

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
          dsNotes.SelectParameters["MilestoneID"].DefaultValue = MilestoneID.ToString();
          dsNotes.SelectParameters["ProjectID"].DefaultValue = ProjectID.ToString();
        }
    }
```

**NOTE** - Code is not tested might need to tweak as your need.

Comment: Please, have a look at the "Update:". Is it possible to modify the HTML data source definition to use the properties?

Comment: I have changed the approach completely. Anyway, thanks for the hints.